# How can I change the base url shown in the store?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager.

In an API, in User Overview tab below url is shown as Production and Sandbox URLs which are correct

http://myapistore.com:8280/railway/2.0

But in the same api under API console tab below url is shown as base url which is incorrect

http://myapistore.com/store:8280

But actually the base url should be http://myapistore.com:8280

So altogether API url would be

http://myapistore.com:8280/railway/2.0/station/getAll

How can I change the base url?

Comment: From where did you set the domain name myapistore.com? Did you set the HostName attribute in carbon.xml as `myapistore.com/store`. If so, that would be wrong. This looks like a config issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my WSO2 API Store my services are shown correctly. When I click on the tab sheet, the URLS are shown correctly even when I hover over these links.

Did you register the service correctly?

[image]

Comment: those are the not the base url. Base url is shown below those in gray.

Comment: When I hover over those linkes, the links shown below in my browser are correct, they show a correct URL

Comment: Base url is shown below those in gray in small text

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured out the answer to your question, but I came here looking for how to change the production URL of an API, and thought I would share the answer to that question here, for any future googlers :)

This is the view we're talking about, the API overview. Notice that the *Production Endpoint* is wrong (should be *worldbank*, not *worldbanks*).

[image: WSO2 API Publisher Overview]

Click on *Edit API* in the top blue bar, and in the second step you'll be able to change it.

[image: WSO2 API Edit API Step 2]
(notice the corrected URL)

I hope this will help someone in the future :)